# Return groupbox containing controls from controller class and modify individual controls

Tags: c#, winforms

Lets say I have an individual groupBox embedded in a winform.

We can call it **grpLocal**

So at this point this grpBox does not contain any individual controls.

Now lets say I require the need for this grpLocal groupbox to contain different controls based off the context in this case different products.

My idea is to create an abstract baseclass which contains a method like this:

```
public abstract GroupBox showContextControls()
```

followed by a number of deriving subclasses (one for each product) which will use this class to do something like this:

```
public override Groupbox showContextControls()
{
  private label = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
  private label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();

  private grpExternal = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();

  this.grpExternal.Controls.Add(this.label );
  this.grpExternal.Controls.Add(this.label2 );

  return grpExternal;
}
```

**Please bear in mind that this example is only for illustration as there a large number of controls to return.**

grpLocal groupbox will then do something like this...

```
grpLocal = controller.showContextControls();
```

So... Onto the question.

Can I then take the dynamically generated "label2" or "label" and modify their properties from the orignal winform??

I would imagine that you can use the [Control.ControlCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class ( this is based off what ive researched myself ) but I cant seem to get my head around how it would work in this instance.

I would like to be able to do something like this to modify the labels properties:

```
grpLocal.label2.text = "this is label 2";
```

Any help is much appreciated and if i have not made myself clear enough please mention in a comment.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem. But one point that might help: You can traverse _all_ of the Controls on a WinForms Form with a recursive method that searches for a specific control. And you can use the Tag property of each Control to identify it, by setting the Tag to some usage-dependent value or reference when you create the Control.

Comment: Sure you can.  Give your controls a [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when you create them.  Then you can search only the GroupBox using [grpLocal.Controls.Find()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @RenniePet My problem is that the controls are generated dynamically from another controller class. The controls are returned as a groupbox container from that class and I need to add the properties to them once this occurs. idle_mind's solution is so far the closest to what i need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign a **Name** to the Label when you create it:

```
        Label label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        label2.Name = "label2";
```

If the Label is contained **directly** by the GroupBox, then you can use:

```
        grpLocal.Controls["label2"].Text = "Hi!";
```

If the Label could be nested within other controls, like a Panel within the GroupBox, then you can use Controls.Find() to **search** for it like this:

```
        Control[] matches = grpLocal.Controls.Find("label2", true);
        if (matches.Length > 0 && matches[0] is Label)
        {
            Label lbl = (Label)matches[0];
            lbl.Text = "Hello World!";
        }
```

Comment: Wow this is great. Is it possible to do the same thing with input controls?

Comment: Solution has been found!